# Using UUID With Spring boot Data

Tags: java, spring

im using UUID in my application as Primary Key i have problem whene find data by id give me exception  error.
**this is Note Class**

> ```
>   package com.example.demo.model;
>
>     import java.util.Date;
>     import java.util.UUID;
>
>     import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
>     import javax.persistence.Entity;
>     import javax.persistence.FetchType;
>     import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
>     import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
>     import javax.persistence.Id;
>     import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
>
>     import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
>     import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage;
>
>
>     @AutoConfigurationPackage
>     @Entity
>     public class Note {
>
>       @Id
>       @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "pg-uuid")
>       @GenericGenerator(name = "pg-uuid",strategy = "uuid2")
>       private UUID id;
>       private String title;
>       private String text;
>       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
>       private Notebook notebook;
>       private Date lastModifiedOn;
>
>
>       public UUID getId() {
>           return id;
>       }
>       public void setId(UUID id) {
>           this.id = id;
>       }
>       public String getTitle() {
>           return title;
>       }
>       public void setTitle(String title) {
>           this.title = title;
>       }
>       public String getText() {
>           return text;
>       }
>       public void setText(String text) {
>           this.text = text;
>       }
>       public Notebook getNotebook() {
>           return notebook;
>       }
>       public void setNotebook(Notebook notebook) {
>           this.notebook = notebook;
>       }
>       public Date getLastModifiedOn() {
>           return lastModifiedOn;
>       }
>       public void setLastModifiedOn(Date lastModifiedOn) {
>           this.lastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
>       }
> ```

**this is NoteController**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.MyMapper;
import com.example.demo.Repository.NoteBookRepository;
import com.example.demo.Repository.NoteRepository;
import com.example.demo.model.Note;
import com.example.demo.model.Notebook;
import com.example.demo.view.NoteViewModle;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/note")
@CrossOrigin
public class NoteController {

    @Autowired
    NoteRepository noteRepository;

    @Autowired
    NoteBookRepository notebookRepository;

    @Autowired
    MyMapper maper;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<NoteViewModle> getAllNote(){
        List<Note> list = this.noteRepository.findAll();
        List<NoteViewModle> noteViewModles = (List<NoteViewModle>) list.stream().map(note ->maper.convertToNodeViewModel(note)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return noteViewModles;
    }

    @GetMapping("/byId/{id}")
    public NoteViewModle getNotreById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        Note note = this.noteRepository.findById(id).orElse(null); 

        if(note == null)
        {

            System.out.println("In If");
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();

        }

        NoteViewModle modle = maper.convertToNodeViewModel(note);

        return modle;
    }

    @GetMapping("/byNoteBook/{notebookId}")
    public List<Note> getNotesByNoteBook(@PathVariable("notebookId") String id)
    {
        return this.noteRepository.findAllByNotebook(this.notebookRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElse(new Notebook()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Note save(@RequestBody NoteViewModle modle)
    {   
        Note note = maper.convertToNodeEntity(modle);
        return this.noteRepository.save(note);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deltebyId/{id}")
    public void deleteNoteById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        this.noteRepository.deleteById(UUID.fromString(id));
    }

}
```

**this is MyMapper to mape the json data**

```
   package com.example.demo;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.example.demo.Repository.NoteBookRepository;
    import com.example.demo.model.Note;
    import com.example.demo.model.Notebook;
    import com.example.demo.view.NoteViewModle;
    import com.example.demo.view.NotebookViewModel;
    @Component
    public class MyMapper {
        @Autowired
        NoteBookRepository bookRepository;

        public NoteViewModle convertToNodeViewModel(Note entity) {
            NoteViewModle modle = new NoteViewModle();
            modle.setId(entity.getId().toString());
            modle.setTitle(entity.getTitle());
            modle.setText(entity.getText());
            modle.setNoteBookId(entity.getNotebook().getId().toString());
            modle.setData(entity.getLastModifiedOn().toString());
            return modle;
        }

        public Note  convertToNodeEntity(NoteViewModle viewModle) {
            Note note = new Note();
            note.setTitle(viewModle.getTitle());
            note.setText(viewModle.getText());
            //note.setLastModifiedOn(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(viewModle.getData()));
            //Notebook notebook = bookRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(viewModle.getId())).orElse(new Notebook());

            return note;
        }


        public NotebookViewModel convertToNotebookViewModel(Notebook entity)
        {
            NotebookViewModel viewModel = new NotebookViewModel();

            viewModel.setId(entity.getId().toString());
            viewModel.setName(entity.getName());
            viewModel.setNumOfNote(entity.getNotes().size());
            return viewModel;
        }

        public Notebook convertToNotebookEntity(NotebookViewModel model) {
            Notebook notebook = new Notebook();
            notebook.setId(UUID.fromString(model.getId()));
            notebook.setName(model.getName());
            return notebook;
        }

    }
```

**this is repositry class**

```
package com.example.demo.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Note;
import com.example.demo.model.Notebook;

@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, UUID> {

    List<Note> findAllByNotebook(Notebook notebook);
}
```

this is error is appears **org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.example.demo.model.Notebook entity with id 7e83b195-eb81-4752-a6fa-a5206c9eb1c6 exists!**